# Speaker protection circuit with polarized capacitor seeing reverse voltage. Why? How?

Tags: protection, electrolytic-capacitor, reverse-polarity

I am looking at this speaker protection circuit found in a vintage Technics receiver.
The signal from the speakers comes from the wire highlighted in green, coming from the output of a class AB power amplification circuit, through an 18\$k\Omega\$ resistor.
My understanding is that if there is any positive DC at the output, that would charge C714 and bias TR704 (and TR702) to conduction, activating the relay which opens the circuit before the bridge rectifier, shutting the receiver off (the negative side of C714 is connected to ground). The RC constant and the level of DC at the output determine how fast TR704 turns on. With negative DC at the output, TR703 would turn on, but C714 would effectively be in reverse.

My questions are the following:

1. What is the reasoning behind such a design choice, and why did the designers not use a non-polarised capacitor?
2. Does C714 still charge even with reverse voltage, and does the usual RC constant apply, or does the circuit work differently with negative DC at the output?

[image: Speaker protection]

Answer (score 1):

If there is DC at the output the relay contacts will cut it off by interrupting the input to the bridge rectifier.

The protection circuit has its own supply D703/C712 that is not interrupted by the relay, and it latches via TR704.

A brief and small negative voltage like that (<1V) is not harmful to the electrolytic cap and it will have the same capacitance value as normal.